# php & mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a code on php to modificate some mysql cells content, but my code are returning the error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`datanasc`,`rg`,`rgemissor`,`cpf`,`sexo`,`cnh`,`tituloeleitor`,`zonaeleitoral`,' at line 1

```
    <?php
    include('mysql.php');
    mysql_select_db("teste", $conexao);

    $schema = array('idfunc', 'nomefunc', 'rg', 'rgemissor', 'cpf', 'cnh', 'reservista', 'estrangeiro', 'tituloeleitor', 'zonaeleitoral', 'sindicato', 'matsindical', 'estadocivil', 'datanasc', 'nacionalidade', 'naturalidade', 'endereco', 'salario', 'expediente', 'cargahoraria', 'beneficiarios', 'admissao', 'numeropis', 'banco', 'agencia', 'dataretroativo', 'datadispensa', 'sexo', 'nomepai', 'nomemae', 'funcao', 'linkfoto');
    $fields = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
        if (in_array($key, $schema)){
            $fields[] = "`".mysql_real_escape_string($key)."`";
            $values[] = "`".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."`";
        }
    }

    $ins = mysql_query("UPDATE funcionarios SET(".implode(",",$fields).") VALUES(".implode(",",$values).")") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Funcionário modificado com sucesso.";


    mysql_close($conexao)
    ?>
```

Comment: that's not the right UPDATE syntax. check here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incorrectly formed because you're basically using an INSERT statement with the word "UPDATE" used in lieu of "INSERT".

An update statement is structured like so:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column = value WHERE column = conditional_value;
```

Whereas you're attempting to perform an UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET(column) VALUES(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of **`update`** is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = value, column_2 = value....
WHERE column1 = value
```

But your query will produce it as

```
UPDATE funcionarios SET column1,column2,... VALUES val1,val2,...
```

Comment: how do i get the number of each column on array?

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
"`".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."`";
```

to

```
"'".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."'";
```

and no need to escape column

```
"`".($key)."`"
```

Then change the code to:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
        if (in_array($key, $schema)){
            $updates[] = " `$key` =  '".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."'";
        }
}
```

and this line:

```
$ins = mysql_query("UPDATE funcionarios SET ".implode(", ", $updates)) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

This means your query isn't correct due to errors.
Print out your query ("Update...) to see the the structure and verify where the error is in your query.
Also, your update statement is incorrect.